# Who or what creats a realm of existance?

Tags: karma

What or who is the cause that a realm of existance comes into being?

Or is such accidentally? Or an unconditioned phenomena? A material-alone phenomena?

What causes your world you "be", have "been", could or will "be"?

Comment: I have closed the question due to being *primarily opinion-based* and I suspect it has been asked with the purpose to teach.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody creates a realm. The physical aspect of a realm is caused mainly by Utu Niyama and Bija Niyama. The mental aspect of a realm is caused mainly by Kamma Niyama and Citta Niyama. Dhamma Niyama affects both mental and physical aspects of a realm.

Comment: So then it not conditioned, or what? Or un-personal conditioned? How should that work? A sublime creator? What's the cause of kamma, for example? Or of Utu?

Comment: Why should there be a creator? Need to get that thought out of the mind

Comment: Nyom told that there is nothing that creates, has no condition. Again, what is the condition of being?

Comment: God, creator Kamma Niyama and Citta Niyama, Utu...? Or what?

Comment: The question assumes that we know "existence" had a beginning. On what basis is this assumption made?

Comment: That you eat, still eat and desire to? Smart @brothereric

Comment: @SamanaJohann. Comment section is not for discussion.